# Why @onclick callback in foreach loop is not invoked, when the items source has changed?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly, .net-5

I have a list of divs with `@onclick` eventhandler within `foreach` loop:

```
<input @onblur="RefreshFilteredItems">
@foreach(var item in FilteredItems)
{
    <div @onclick="_ => OnItemClick(item)" key="@item">@item</div>
}

@code {
   RefreshFilteredItems()
   {
     FilteredItems = AllItems; 
   }
}
```

When user clicks on `<div>`, OnItemClick is invoked as expected.

However, when the input is focused first and the user clicks on one of the divs, the @onblur is called and @onclick is ignored.

The cause is, that RefreshFilteredItems which is called before OnItemClick changes the FilteredItems collection.

1. Why only onblur callback is invoked and not also onclick?
2. How to I handle the click event?

Here is a simplified demo
https://blazorrepl.com/repl/GbkQEMbG52kiwSuD01

Comment: If the list is not so big I would bind-Value input to a property which setter is also calling RefreshFilteredItems. That way you will avoid using onblur and your filtered list will be always up to date. Additionally, you can fine-tune that with some delay to allow the user to write the whole search query before refreshing.

Comment: @JanBejvl: That is not my scenario. I do use @@oninput to to real time filtering and I reset  the filter in @@onlur. Check the REPL

Comment: May I ask about the motivation, why would you try to refresh filtered items like that? Where will the item click take you? From the user interface pov, isn't that bad that there is some query in the search bar but results are not filtered (after onblur)? Maybe we would be able to find another way..

Comment: Off topic, but my scenario is a combo box with many items. You can filter the items by typing to the textbox and then select the item. However, when the combobox looses focus, the filter should be reset. It's a standard behavior of many comboboxes

Comment: Just idea, I would try: to have isOpened property, then handle onfocus of the combobox wrapper div (with tabindex to be focusable). On focus set isOpened to true and display filtered items. Also use jsinterop to register document onclick where compare if clicked node is child of combobox wrapper. If the node is not child, call back from js to your combobox component where you can do all the stuff you need set isOpened to false, refresh the state. But I'm still not sold on the refreshing idea, I though that comboxoes have this little cross icon, to reset the searched query..

Comment: I have solved it using JS interop, where I manually call from JS to .NET from onblur event and setTimeout();

Answer (score 2):

`OnBlur` is replacing the DOM and the click never arrives to the new divs because the click is sent before the new list exists. Also doesn't arrive to old list because `OnBlur` remove it.

```
Users enters 'c' on input box.
User clics on list item:
   - OnBlur is executed, the list is replaced
   - Click event is lost because old list not exists
```

This is really easy to check, just replace your current `OnBlur` with this snipped, this `OnBLur` delays the list replace to allow time to clicks arrive to the list item:

```cs
    async Task OnBlur() {
        await Task.Delay(100);  // <-- delay to allow time
        Items = GenerateItems().ToList();
    }
```

```
Users enters 'c' on input box.
User clics on list item:
   - OnBlur start execution with 100 milliseconds delay
   - Click event arrives to the old list
   - OnBlur finish replacing the list
```

Notice that this is not a solution, this is the explanation about why your code doesn't run as you expected.

I guess you shared a minimum working sample just to understand how blazor works. The solution is to redesign your component and avoid this combination: OnBlur + OnClick.

Check it out at https://blazorrepl.com/repl/QPOmkWPf50ybJCN344

[image]

Comment: Yeah, the problem is, that this is very problematic in Blazor Server Side, because the delay might be greater. BTW, it does not work either. Try to type 'C' and then click on 3rd item. You would have to use async void instead async Task, so that the eventhandler is not awaited

Comment: Liero, sorry, my English is so bad and is hard to understand you. I posted an screen recording clicking on 3rd item and selecting it. This is not the expected behavior? Regards.

Comment: Sorry, my bad :( When you type 'C' the third item does work indeed. The fourth doesn't. The reason is, that when you type 'C', the first 3 items are unchanged before and after onblur. Fourth item '10 ABCD' is replaced by '4 EFGH'. Notice that '10 ABCD' is not selected

Comment: This helped me solve a related problem. Just some gratitude for you all ;-)